# C# winmm.dll mp3 player Fast Forward method?

Tags: c#, audio, winmm

I am using winmm.dll  to make a basic mp3 player.
 I have a little problem with my FFW method. basically nothing happens  when I activate it.

You can probably figure what I am trying to do.

the first 6 comment out lines,  hold a working sample code,   when running my loop it doesnt work for me,   What have I done wrong ?

```
public void FFW()
{
    //string cmd1 = "set MyMp3 time format ms";
    //mciSendString(cmd1, null, 0, 0);
    //cmd1 = "seek MyMp3 to 8000";
    //mciSendString(cmd1, null, 0, 0);
    //cmd = "play MyMp3";
    //mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);

    int ffw5sec = 5000;

    while (isPlaying == true)
    {
        string cmd = "set MyMp3 time format ms";
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);
        cmd = "seek MyMp3 to " + ffw5sec.ToString();
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);
        cmd = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);

        ffw5sec += 5000;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ohh, I got it working when I took my code out from the loop....

my solution:
  the Skip feature is not optimal, but atleast its doing what I was looking for, I think I need to add a timer in the future, to calculate a better skip.

```
int ffw5sec = 5000;

public void FFW()
{
    if(isPlaying == true)
    {
        string cmd = "set MyMp3 time format ms";
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);
        cmd = "seek MyMp3 to " + ffw5sec.ToString();
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);
        cmd = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(cmd, null, 0, 0);

        ffw5sec += 5000;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer, because it's too vague. Are you saying that you just eliminated the **while** loop? Please be clearer/more specific about how you resolved the problem, then mark your answer as accepted.